# Fluent NHibernate Cascade - Which side?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent

In using Fluent NHibernate, I can't seem to find a good explanation of when you use the cascading option on the References side vs. the HasMany side.

What's the difference (if any) in mapping the following...

```
References(...).Cascade.All();
```

vs

```
HasMany(...).Cascade.All();
```

My question stems from a problem when saving a parent (root) entity. Once it's saved, I want to insure that all child objects are also persisted.

Comment: If I have a cascade set in the database and in NHibernate, is that OK?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You put the cascade on the side that you are saving.

If you save the parent and want to cascade to the children, put the cascade mapping on the parent.